# How to modify capistrano deploy to automatically run migrations in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

Right now, I have to run cap deploy and cap deploy:migrations if there are migrations to be run.

how I modify the cap deploy task to run migrations.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just add:

```
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"
```

to your `config/deploy.rb`.

Answer (score 10):

Running `"cap deploy:migrations"` is equivalent to running `"cap deploy"` && subsequently `"cap deploy:migrate"` in one command.

To view the description for deploy:migrations, just use the -e option:

```
cap -e deploy:migrations
```

will give you this output:

> ```
> cap deploy:migrations
> ```
>
> Deploy and run pending migrations. This will work similarly to the
>   'deploy' task, but will also run any pending migrations (via the
>   'deploy:migrate' task) prior to updating the symlink. Note that the
>   update in this case it is not atomic, and transactions are not used,
>   because migrations are not guaranteed to be reversible.