# No migration at deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I have simple question. My app at deploy dont't start `rake db:migrate` at production env. I Did not create `deploy.rb` I got it already prepared. `deploy.rb` is working, but command `'deploy:migrate'` don't work. I don't know, how correctly ask this question. But I think this problem with `:role`. Maybe `rake db:migrate` need to describe? Like this:

```
namespace :db do

  desc "Rake migration"
    task :migrate, :roles => :db do
      run "cd #{current_path} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate"
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question...

There is already a `deploy:migrate` task defined as part of capistrano, which you just have to add a hook for in your `deploy.rb` and it will run.  See [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897555/152786) on doing that.

You shouldn't need the code you've defined above, but if you do then note that you aren't defining `deploy:migrate` you're defining `db:migrate`.