# What advantage Capistrano has over direct github clone ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, capistrano

I was wondering what advantage Capistrano has over direct cloning of files from github to my server for my RoR app ?

Comment: They do something else entirely? Or rather, Capistrano's features are a large strict superset of "just cloning a repo". As I understand Capistrano, at its core is simply being able to SSH to a lot of servers and perform a bunch of actions - any actions, not just cloning a repo - in an **automated** way. This means you can update other components of your application you have besides the Rails bit.

Comment: E.g. an application like Twitter will consist of many, many cooperating services running on completely separate servers, of which the notorious Rails part only handles displaying HTML and accepting user input. The bulk of the processing is done elsewhere, and some of these services may need more complicated deployment procedures than just updating a git clone. This also implies that if *your* app is a simple monolithic Rails setup, you might in fact not really need a more complicated deployment tool. That doesn't however mean that tool has no advantages.

Comment: That said, I can think of one off the top of my head. You might want to configure the server to run your application's worker(s) (mongrel or unicorn or whichever is the popular one this week) when it boots up, by depositing a script in `/etc/init.d`, and start the worker if it's not running. (Assuming you're not using a web host with some sort of direct Rails support.) With just a `git clone`, you'd have to do this manually, instead of having Capistrano check if the file exist, if not generate it, etc. whenever you deploy, and having this work on a "clean" server automatically.

Comment: Thanks, so how I can just push the code to the server using capistrano and it will take care of database too ? since the biggest headache with using github repo is I need to manually upload the db to server too as githu won't take care of it

Comment: It won't happen completely automatically, the idea is that you can write a script that will, say, run the Rails migration stuff *after* updating the app code, but before *restarting* the app. That said, seeing as it's a mature tool, chances are you can find a plugin that does this stuff without having to write it from scratch. (Some Googling indicates this might actually be built-in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895450/how-to-modify-capistrano-deploy-to-automatically-run-migrations-in-rails-3-0)

Comment: Also, you can probably look for tutorials on how to start from scratch. (Like, say, http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/basic-deployment-with-capistrano/)